# Nuxt: Preventing app.template.html from being re-created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I need to customize the `app.template.html` file for some reasons, for example due to being forced to add a trust seal which I want to display in a certain area and this cannot be done by adding the script to the config file. However, when I run the `npm run dev` command, this file is re-created and all my edits are lost. How can I prevent it from being re-created? or is there any better solutions? 
Keep in mind that injection of the script to the DOM is a silly solution because it results in a mismatch error, and `v-html` fails to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/nuxt/docs/blob/master/en/guide/views.md). The documentation said, creating an `app.html` at the root of the project will override the default template.